# libc addresses not accessible for return oritented programming

Tags: c, linux, unix, ubuntu-14.04

I wrote a program for demonstrating ROP attack. I referred to a website for steps. Debugged my program several time to remove any basic knowledge errors. But still the program fails saying that the address to where the libc files for the gadgets are located, is invalid. But I have cross checked in several ways.

Why I cannot access the address pointing to a gadget in the libc file?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void attackfxn(char *string){
  char buffer[256];
  strcpy(buffer,string);
  printf(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  attackfxn(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

[This](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28479.pdf) is the website I referred to.

If you need screenshots of anything please ask.
I used the gdb peta and ropeme for pulling gadgets.

The error that is get says "Invalid PC address". But that address is supposed to be the base address of libc file + offset address of the gadget found using ROPeme. Why does the debugger says that address is inaccessible ?

The program is compiled using -fno-stack-protector and ASLR is turned off!!

Comment: At least I'm having a hard time understanding anything here. It's a program, which doesn't do much. How does this relate to gadgets or ROP or something?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: The idea is to use the string to overflow the buffer, replacing the address the function would return to with an address to an useful address in the C library. These addresses are called gadgets, and typically set the return value register to a desired value followed by another return. This changes what the caller thinks the function did, for example changes an error result to a successful result, and thus forms a basis for an exploit.

Comment: Yes, that is what ROP attack is. My problem is, when I was trying to do a similar attack following the steps on that website, I get an error saying "Invalid $PC address". This address is supposed to be the base address of libc file + offset address of the gadget I found using the ROPeme tool. How come that address is invalid, there should be a gadget at that address, right?

Comment: make sure (via /proc/{processID}/maps) that the library you intend to use is readable and executable.